# Sort Array of Hashes Keys

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

I am looking for a solution to sort the Hash keys in an Array.

```
arr = [{"name"=>"Product Management", "id"=>647628}, {"name"=>"Sales", "id"=>647630}]

arr.each {|inner_hash| inner_hash.sort}
```

Expected Result:

```
[{"id"=>647628, "name"=>"Product Management"}, {"id"=>647630, "name"=>"Sales"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you don't need to sort hashes, but you can

```
arr.map { |h| h.sort.to_h }

# => [{"id"=>647628, "name"=>"Product Management"}, {"id"=>647630, "name"=>"Sales"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use ruby `Hash#sort_by` to sort the elements of a Hash:

```
arr.map { |inner_hash| inner_hash.sort_by(&:first).to_h }
>> [{"id"=>647628, "name"=>"Product Management"}, {"id"=>647630, "name"=>"Sales"}]
```